# MyPy doesn't complain when calling a function with distinct types which are declared as TypeVar

Tags: python, mypy

I would have expected to see an error after running MyPy targeting a file with these contents:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def do_nothing(one_arg: T, other_arg: T) -> None:
    return

do_nothing(1, 2)
do_nothing(1, "abc")
do_nothing(1, None)
do_nothing("abc", None)
do_nothing([1, 2, 3], { "a": "b"})
```

But I only get `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`.

My understanding is that a function having arguments of type `T` means that such function can only receive arguments of the same type. In this case, only `do_nothing(1, 2)` should have had passed.

What am I missing?

Comment: `1` and `"abc"` have a common type, though: `object`. Since you aren't doing anything else with `T`, no contradictions arise from unifying `T ~ object`.

Comment: You are right. I just tested with: 
```
def do_nothing(one_arg: T, other_arg: T) -> T:
    return one_arg

r = do_nothing(1, "abc")
reveal_type(r)
```
And got: `Revealed type is "builtins.object"`

Could you please post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Pep-483 explains this: https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#type-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are allowing `T` to be anything. That effectively means that `T` is bound to `object` meaning that any subtype of object is allowed.
mypy resolves types to the most common type possible. `object` is common for any type. Thus, it's ok to pass anything even "different" types.

`TypeVar('T')` expresses that your function doesn't require any protocol additional to one provided by `object` to be implemented in passed types.

So, unless you are going to call some methods on arguments that require the same protocol but for unrelated types there is no way to force such a restriction with mypy.

Consider a counter example:

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T', bound=bytes|str)
```

In this case mypy will restrict arguments to be either both `str` or both `bytes` because

```py
>>> issubclass(str, bytes)
False
>>> issubclass(bytes, str)
False
```

`str` and `bytes` cannot be resolved to a common type that is above the `bytes|str` bound.

See [`typing.TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) docs.